# User Defined XMLNS in Primefaces (xhtml)

Tags: jsf, xhtml, xml-namespaces

Can we include our own xml file in xmlns tag

Example: Consider a file "myxhtmlfile.xhtml ".. in this we could add xml namespaces like,

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

and etc.. [Note:In primefaces.org/ui (consists of many .xml files)]

I've an xml file "myxmlfile.xml" in my system drive (say D:/ Drive) so, what is the approach do we need follow for adding my own xml files ("myxmlfile.xml") in the xhtml file.
There are some tags in myxmlfile.xml file, which i need to use just like 'p' tags (primefaces tags)

Eg: `<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>`

My requirement is like :(I should be able to use all the tags that are defined in myxmlfile.xml) like,

`<m:mymessages id="mymessages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>`

i've tried many methods like placing the both files together in same folder and adding this type of lines`(xmlns:m="D:/resources/xml")` in the xhtml file, but found no luck.

I'm using primefaces 3.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is `myxmlfile.xml`? A Facelets tag file? Why the `.xml` extension?

Comment: Hi BalusC: In Brief, consider primefaces 3.2 jar. In PrimeFaces\src\main\resources-maven-jsf\ui, there are some xml files, which are been used to call the primefaces class files (and ofcourse some self defined tags). In my case, I've to call the class files of own project through these type of xml files, which will be useful for primefaces tags as well as my own set of functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is composite components. 
Take a look at this blog : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your reply.. But my task of work is entirely different. please read above comment to BalusC. I need to override the primefaces xml file to call my own class files.

Comment: You want to add you own set of components to the primefaces one ? If so, i think you'll need to rebuild primefaces from source but that's beyond my knowledge. Sry !

Comment: I Don't want to modify the source code of primefaces. For some functionality I need to write custom widgets, which uses my own classes instead of primefaces classes.(and yes, the functionality is not there in primefaces that's why im trying to call my own classes) Remaining classes and other fuctionalities of primefaces will remain same, only few need to be modified(not in source code) as per my requirement.